# Rotate Index by time In Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

How can I configure Spring Data Elasticsearch to "rotate" indexes, such as for logstash for example?

I mean, with logstash we have an index for every day and refer to indexes as logstash-*. There a kind of index templating referenced in docs: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-templates.html

Can I write something like:

```
@Document(indexName="index-{date_today}", ...)
```

Where date_today is exactly current date.
How can I reproduce the same behavior with spring data elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you cant use the index created by the annotation @Document, you have to manually create indexed using ElasticSearchTemplate.

I have answer this in [Creating Indices name Dynamically in Elasticsearch using Spring-Data Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894618/creating-indices-name-dynamically-in-elasticsearch-using-spring-data-elasticsear)