# Spring Data - SpelEvaluationException - Property or field cannot be found on null

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Spring Expression Language to configure an annotation from Spring Data ElasticSearch dynamically. The solutions I tried ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38530650) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255240)) produce the following error in my case:

```
Caused by: SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field
'DbCreatorIndexNameConfig' cannot be found on null
```

The annotation in question is:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = DbCreatorIndexNameConfig.class)
@Document(indexName = "#{DbCreatorIndexNameConfig.indexName()}", type = "video", 
shards = 1, replicas = 0)
public class Video implements EsModel {
//...
```

The bean in question:

```
@Configuration("DbCreatorIndexNameConfig")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Video.class)
public class DbCreatorIndexNameConfig {

    @Value("video_default")
    public String indexName;

    @Bean
    public String indexName() {
        return indexName;
    }

    public void setIndexName(String indexName) {
        this.indexName = indexName;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I have made sure, that the bean is wired into the application context via `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EsSpringTemplate.class, DbCreatorIndexNameConfig.class);`
- I have made sure that Spring knows the needed beans. They appear in
  `annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()`.
- indexName must be a constant. Therefor it seems only possible to use SpEL

Any idea is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modify it as follows:- You have to use '@' to access a bean in spel

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@DbCreatorIndexNameConfig.indexName()}", type = "video", 
shards = 1, replicas = 0)
```

Comment: let me know if it didnt solved the issue. If it did, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this, but the result is another exception: `SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'DbCreatorIndexNameConfig'`

Comment: I dont know if it sounds absurd or not but have you tried using @indexName only?

Comment: yes, in all variants. indexName, @indexName, indexName(), @indexName(). Even tried a constructor: `@Bean
    public DbCreatorIndexNameConfig dbCreatorIndexNameConfig() ...`

Comment: stay the same: `SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'indexName'` - When I use @indexName() it becomes: `SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lparen(()'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153124/discussion-between-arslananjum-and-rapstacke).